# Using the mv command to move a file to a destination stored in a variable

Tags: unix

I want to move a file called dog to `$HOME/deleted2`.
The unix command I use is:

```
mv dog $HOME/deleted2
```

However I want to move it to the exact same destination but this time `$HOME/deleted2` is stored in a hidden file called .rm.cfg 
I want to extract the location from .rm.cfg, this file contains one line which says `$HOME/deleted2`.

Here is what I did:

```
pathname=$(cat $HOME/.rm.cfg),
mv dog $pathname.
```

However this time I get an error saying `$HOME/deleted2` does not exist. Why is this?
Sorry for not putting it in code format, I tried to indent by fours spaces but it did not work.

Comment: Do you actually have a file named `cat`, or do you simply want to get the name of the file by running the command `cat <some_file>`? I didn't get what you're trying to do. Please, tell us also which shell you are using.

Comment: i have changed the the name of the cat file to dog to avoid confusion, the dog file exists. I want to move the dog file to $HOME/deleted2, but this path is stored in a file called .rm.cfg and I want to extract it. I did extract it but it says $HOME/deleted2 does not exist when it does. I am using bash.

Comment: I think the "cat" is the problem. Can you update your question with your "dog" file?

Comment: Run `set -x` before the commands you showed us. This will help debugging what goes inside each parameter you passed to `mv`.

Comment: ok i did set -x pathname=$(cat $HOME/.rm.cfg): i get the follwong : ++ cat .rm.cfg,   + set -x 'pathname=$HOME/delteded2'

Comment: Can you try adding a single quote to cat -> 'cat'

Comment: i have changed the cat file to dog

Comment: Also change $HOME/deleted2 => $HOME/deleted2/

Comment: @user3809938 If it was an exact *copy-paste* of the shell output, you may have a typo in your `.rm.cfg` file: `$HOME/de*lted*ed2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat $HOME/.rm.cfg` will only "outputs" the raw file, but it does not evaluate variables.

To put the full interpreted string in your `pathname` variable, you need to evaluate it:

```
pathname=$(eval echo $(cat $HOME/.rm.cfg))
```

Comment: `$(cat $HOME/.rm.cfg)` returns "$HOME/deleted2", `eval` will then executes `echo $HOME/.rm.cfg`. See answers on [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash).